# Strange PHP Phenomenon On Magento Product View Page that gets Interpreted different by Different Browsers

Tags: php, magento

I have a strange problem with the below script. I've been working on it all day. I'm trying to show the top seller per category in a side block on the product view page in Magento Shopping Cart. This script works but not the same in IE (all). Actually IE gets it right and every other browser I've tried gets it wrong.

Here's the problem. It's php and php is suppose to be a server side language. But it appears that IE is getting a different message. Below, you'll notice I have a red border around one part and a green border around another part. IE gets the red border and the rest get the green border. The red border has the "Category Name" and it works in IE but the green border ...if I put the script for the category name it prints a error message.

Except for the multiple "division by zero" warnings I get (don't know why) I would like to know why two kinds of browsers get two different messages if php is a server side language!?

Thanks

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Branko Ajzele | http://activecodeline.com | branko.ajzele@surgeworks.com
 * @license GPL
 */

/**
*
*
05/06/2011 Modified by Erik Gabor | erikvail@gmail.com | http://www.mage-contacts.com
* @license GPL

*/ 

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$totalPerPage = ($this->show_total) ? $this->show_total :1;
$counter = 1;
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                              ->setStoreId($storeId)
                  ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                              ->addOrderedQty()
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);


        if ($current_category = Mage::registry('current_category'))
    $_productCollection->addCategoryFilter($current_category);
    $_productCollection->setPage(1,$totalPerPage);  
        $_productCollection->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);

        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');


//Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Product_Collection
?>

<?php

/**
 * Each product in foreach loop is array of following fields
 *

Array
(
    [ordered_qty] => 2.0000
    [entity_id] => 150
    [entity_type_id] => 10
    [attribute_set_id] => 62
    [type_id] => simple
    [sku] => 500gb7200
    [category_ids] => 29,36
    [created_at] => 2008-07-25 01:12:44
    [updated_at] => 2008-07-25 02:09:26
    [has_options] => 0
    [visibility] => 4
    [hardrive] => 500 GB
    [meta_keyword] =>
    [description] => 500GB- 7200RPM, SATA 3.0Gb/s, 32MB Cache
    [short_description] => 500GB - 7200RPM, SATA 3.0Gb/s, 32MB Cache
    [custom_layout_update] =>
    [status] => 1
    [tax_class_id] => 1
    [manufacturer] => 118
    [weight] => 1.0000
    [price] => 299.0000
    [name] => Western Digital 500GB HD - 7200RPM
    [url_key] => 500gb-7200rpm
    [gift_message_available] => 2
    [harddrive_speed] => 7200 rpm
    [meta_title] =>
    [meta_description] =>
    [thumbnail] => /w/e/western-digital-500gb-hd-7200rpm.jpg
    [small_image] => /w/e/western-digital-500gb-hd-7200rpm.jpg
    [image] => /w/e/western-digital-500gb-hd-7200rpm.jpg
    [custom_design] =>
    [options_container] => container2
    [stock_item (Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item)] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 119
            [product_id] => 150
            [stock_id] => 1
            [qty] => 999994.0000
            [min_qty] => 0.0000
            [use_config_min_qty] => 1
            [is_qty_decimal] => 0
            [backorders] => 0
            [use_config_backorders] => 1
            [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
            [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
            [max_sale_qty] => 0.0000
            [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
            [is_in_stock] => 1
            [low_stock_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
            [manage_stock] => 0
            [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
            [product (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)] => *** RECURSION ***
        )

    [is_salable] => 1
)


 */
 $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count();


 if($current_category && $_collectionSize) :

?>
<div class="block" style="border:1px solid red">
<div class="block-title">
<strong><span><?php echo $current_category->getName()  ?> <?php echo $this->__('Bestseller') ?></span></strong>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="block" style="border:1px solid green">
<div class="block-title">
<strong><span> <?php echo $this->__('Bestseller') ?></span></strong>
</div>
 <?php endif;?>
  <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(195); ?>" width="195" height="284" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>

                <h2 class="product-name" style="float:left;width:180px;margin:7px"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                 <div style="float:left;width:180px;margin:7px">
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php  echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()) ?>

                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add', array('product' => $_product->getId())) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a id="wish" href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><a id="compare" href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
</div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough information to quickly debug your problem (where is this code, how is it running), but here's two quick suggestions that might point you in the right direction.

First, save the source (using the View -> Source) command of your web browser (not the various web inspectors, which will sometimes massage the DOM into a correct form) and diff the output from the two browsers. You may have a case where the output **is** identical, but something about the CSS rules and javascript results in the browser page looking different.

If there are differences in the page, then what's likely happening is the browser is sending different information to PHP from IE vs. your other browsers **and/or** there's different information in you PHP session in the different browsers that cause the PHP code to come up with different results.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I looked at the source output from two different browsers and one shows different html than the other one. I have deleted all sessions out of my Magento var/session folder. I deleted all browsers history and cookies. I deleted everything re-index. Might be something in the css like display none but not just for one particular browser. It works as is but one browser shows the Category name and  the others don't. I would just like to have the category name on the block header but I've tried every script I could find on the net and none of them work in this situation.